# Setting editable options in Timevis when using R/Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, timeline

I am creating a timeline using R/Shiny timevis package.  I can see in R/Shiny that you can setOptions so that the items are editable.  I can see in visjs documentation that you can then set individual manipulation actions (see below).

Is there a way for me to set these options from R/Shiny using setOptions?  Thanks...

```
      timevis(groups = project_groups) %>%
      setOptions(list(editable = TRUE,
         ...
```

https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/docs/timeline/#Editing_Items

```
  // enable or disable all manipulation actions
  var options = {
    editable: true       // true or false
  };

  // enable or disable individual manipulation actions
  var options = {
    editable: {
      add: true,         // add new items by double tapping
      updateTime: true,  // drag items horizontally
      updateGroup: true, // drag items from one group to another
      remove: true,       // delete an item by tapping the delete button top right
      overrideItems: false  // allow these options to override item.editable
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can set individual options. Here is an example:

```
library(timevis)
timevis(
  data.frame(start = Sys.Date(), content = "Today"),
  options = list(editable = list(add = TRUE, remove = FALSE))
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dean - much appreciated!!!  Thanks for creating timevis.  Jareem